# Incorrect Ubuntu server time

Tags: ubuntu, time, time-synchronization, date, timestamp

I use 14.04.1-Ubuntu. When execute `date` in command line, I get time which about 1 min different comparing [Greenwich Mean Time](https://time.is/GMT) or other source. I synchronized it using `sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov` few months ago but it jumped away again. Why does it happen? How to keep accurate time on Ubuntu continuously?

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install ntp package
   `sudo apt-get install ntp`
2. Edit `/etc/ntp.conf` for your neighbor ntp server
   `sudo vi +/^server /etc/ntp.conf`
3. Reload ntp configuration
   `sudo service ntp reload`
4. Check time sync status with `ntpq -p`. It takes some while for synchronized (*)  status.
   `sudo ntpq -p`

Ref: Ubuntu 14.04 >> Ubuntu Server Guide >> Networking

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/NTP.html

Answer (score 6):

> How to keep accurate time on Ubuntu continuously?

By enabling the `ntpd` service and running it continuously.

> I synchronized it using `sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov` few months ago but it jumped away again. Why does it happen?

The hardware clock in computer systems is simply not accurate enough.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately Ubuntu hasn't added the disclaimer from NTP.org's `ntp-4.2.*\html\ntpdate.html` manual to Ubuntu's [`ntpdate(8)` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/ntpdate.8.html), like for example [FreeBSD has](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ntpdate):

> `ntpdate` - set the date and time via NTP
>
> Disclaimer: This program has known bugs and deficiencies and nobody
>   has volunteered to fix them in a long time. The good news is the
>   functionality originally intended for this program is available in the
>   `ntpd` and `sntp` programs.
>
> See the [Deprecating `ntpdate` topic](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate) in the NTP
>   Support wiki for a thorough discussion and analysis of the issues. See
>   the `-q` command line option in the `ntpd` - Network Time Protocol (NTP)
>   daemon page and/or the `sntp` - Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP)
>   Client page. After a suitable period of mourning, the `ntpdate` program
>   will be retired from this distribution.

If Ubuntu did so, you wouldn't even have to Google for this, not to mention asking it from Serverfault.

Comment: To be fair, if you use `ntpd -q` only once in months, you won't yield better results.

Comment: True, but the point of this answer is that if this disclaimer was in the manpage, it would have directed OP to the right direction: `ntpdate` is deprecated, let's see what there is on `man ntpd`. Now it's not even in the "See also" section. I truly hope that reading `man ntpd` would enlighten the topic enough for not using merely `-q`.

Comment: +1 for including the deprecation notice.